# Determine limit as $x$ approaches infinity for integral with $x$ and infinity as lower/upper limits

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

Not sure how to phrase the title..

$$y(x) = e^x \int_x^∞ \frac{dt}{te^t}$$

so $\lim_{x \to ∞} y(x)$

As x approaches ∞ the integral approaches 0 and $e^x$ approaches ∞, not sure what to do, should I substitute somehow to make it into an improper integer? But then I'll still have $e^x$

Answer (score 3):

You can apply L'Hopital's rule to$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_x^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{te^t}}{e^{-x}}.$$

Comment: Oh so the limit would be 0 then. How should I prove or justify that I believe that y(x) is decreasing?

Comment: @JohnDoe Why do you feel the need of proving that?

Comment: Every time we need to give a limit we also have to prove if it decreasing/increasing if x>0. I believe it is decreasing since the closer it gets to infinity the closer to zero it gets, but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: @JohnDoe So, since $\frac{\sin x}{e^x}$ is neither increasing or decresing, you think that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{e^x}$ either does not exist or it exists but it is not $0$. Am I right?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if I'm even thinking anymore

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\displaystyle 0\leq \int_x^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{te^t} = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u+x}du\leq \frac 1x \int_0^\infty e^{-u}du=\frac{1}x \to 0$